# Google Earth server inaccesible

Tags: help, censorship

I'm from Italy and the Google Earth server seems inaccesible because of censorship. 
I've tried many free Web proxies without success.
Can Tor help me to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to access Google Earth (or any other censored site) by using Tor. Take note that Google Earth plugin for browsers will need Javascript enabled, but that may not be a concern for you if bypassing censorship is what you want, not total anonymity.

In order to use Tor, the easiest way to download, install and run the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://torproject.org). It is a customized Firefox browser that allows you to surf the web using Tor. So make sure you use the Web plugin of Google Earth, not the Desktop software, as the latter wouldn't be able to run on the Tor extensions provided by the browser.

If Tor is blocked by your ISP, you can use [Pluggable Transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en) to be able to connect to the Tor network. It is an option that is now embedded in the Tor Browser, where you can specify when it first runs if you want to connect to the Tor network directly or using Tor bridges if access to Tor is blocked.